# nginx+uwsgi stops responding after auto reload

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, supervisord

I have a docker container based off Alpine 3.16
It runs nginx/uwsgi with supervisord for a django based app.

This Dockerfile has been pretty much the same for several years now. Auto reload worked fine.

Suddenly today after the container rebuilt, auto-reload fails in a strange way - it get hung up for minutes and then works - here is the log:

```
2023-02-20 14:57:28,771 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2023-02-20 14:57:28,771 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2023-02-20 14:57:28,771 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2023-02-20 14:57:28,771 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2023-02-20 14:57:29,774 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 7
2023-02-20 14:57:29,774 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 7
2023-02-20 14:57:29,777 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 8
2023-02-20 14:57:29,777 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 8
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/lib/acme/lib/wsgi/uwsgi.ini
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.21 (64bit) on [Mon Feb 20 14:57:29 2023] ***
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - compiled with version: 12.2.1 20220924 on 15 February 2023 09:44:04
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - os: Linux-6.1.11-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 09 Feb 2023 20:06:08 +0000
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - nodename: b5d838731ef0
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - machine: x86_64
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - clock source: unix
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - pcre jit disabled
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - detected number of CPU cores: 16
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - current working directory: /
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - chdir() to /usr/lib/acme/lib
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - detected max file descriptor number: 1073741816
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8001 fd 3
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - Python version: 3.10.10 (main, Feb  9 2023, 02:08:14) [GCC 12.2.1 20220924]
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x7fc3ff0b4020
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - python threads support enabled
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - mapped 364520 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Session Identifier: 1675966916.7616582
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x7fc3ff0b4020 pid: 8 (default app)
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 8)
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 26, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 28, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 2
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 31, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - Python auto-reloader enabled
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 3
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 34, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 14:57:29 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 4
2023-02-20 14:57:30,899 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-02-20 14:57:30,899 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-02-20 14:57:30,899 INFO success: uwsgi entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-02-20 14:57:30,899 INFO success: uwsgi entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
[2023-02-20 14:57:55]
2023-02-20 14:58:15 - [uwsgi-python-reloader] module/file /usr/lib/acme/lib/./acme_portal/../acme_api/acme.py has been modified
2023-02-20 14:58:15 - ...gracefully killing workers...
2023-02-20 14:58:15 - Gracefully killing worker 1 (pid: 26)...
2023-02-20 14:58:15 - Gracefully killing worker 4 (pid: 34)...
2023-02-20 14:58:15 - Gracefully killing worker 3 (pid: 31)...
2023-02-20 14:58:15 - Gracefully killing worker 2 (pid: 28)...
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - worker 3 buried after 1 seconds
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - worker 4 buried after 1 seconds
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - binary reloading uWSGI...
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - chdir() to /
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - closing all non-uwsgi socket fds > 2 (max_fd = 1073741816)...
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - found fd 3 mapped to socket 0 (:8001)

***********************************************************************************

2023-02-20 14:59:44 - running /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/lib/acme/lib/wsgi/uwsgi.ini
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.21 (64bit) on [Mon Feb 20 14:59:44 2023] ***
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - compiled with version: 12.2.1 20220924 on 15 February 2023 09:44:04
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - os: Linux-6.1.11-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 09 Feb 2023 20:06:08 +0000
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - nodename: b5d838731ef0
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - machine: x86_64
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - clock source: unix
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - pcre jit disabled
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - detected number of CPU cores: 16
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - current working directory: /
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - chdir() to /usr/lib/acme/lib
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - detected max file descriptor number: 1073741816
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2023-02-20 14:59:44 - uwsgi socket 0 inherited INET address :8001 fd 

***********************************************************************************

2023-02-20 15:04:08 - Python version: 3.10.10 (main, Feb  9 2023, 02:08:14) [GCC 12.2.1 20220924]
2023-02-20 15:04:08 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x7f8d19c79020
2023-02-20 15:04:08 - python threads support enabled
2023-02-20 15:04:08 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2023-02-20 15:04:08 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2023-02-20 15:04:08 - mapped 364520 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
2023-02-20 15:04:08 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Session Identifier: 1675966916.7616582
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x7f8d19c79020 pid: 8 (default app)
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 8)
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 38, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 40, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 2
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 43, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - Python auto-reloader enabled
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 3
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 46, cores: 1)
2023-02-20 15:04:09 - spawned 1 offload threads for uWSGI worker 4
[2023-02-20 15:04:09]
```

The lines of asterisks is where the whole thing stalls - it does so twice

These 2 following messages are something I am seeing for the first time

```
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - closing all non-uwsgi socket fds > 2 (max_fd = 1073741816)...
2023-02-20 14:58:16 - found fd 3 mapped to socket 0 (:8001)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?
Is it somehow related to my Linux kernel version? Or is it nginx or uwsgi?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I tried downgrading versions of everything one by one, starting with the container Alpine build version, uwsgi, supervisord version, then my Linux kernel.

None of these helped.

Finally downgraded docker from 1:23.0.1-1 to 1:20.10.23-1 and it works as before now.